# HTML table takes too long to dynamically create when rows are greater than 4k-8k

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, html-table

I'm creating td and th based on json data, but it takes too long. 
HTML table takes too long to dynamically create when rows are greater than 4k-8k. How do I improve the performance?

I have an application which is used for data analysis and I'm having a few performance issues with the creation of the table. The data is extracted from documents and it is important that all data is presented on one page (pagination is not an option unfortunately).

Using jQuery, I make an ajax request to the server to retrieve the data. On completion of the request, I pass the data to an output function.

```
 function getApplicationReport() {
            var selector = document.getElementById("excelDataTable");
            var Region = document.getElementById("watchedapp");
            var Regionvalue = Region.options[Region.selectedIndex].value;

            var Business = document.getElementById("application");


            var Businessvalue = Business.options[Business.selectedIndex].value;


            $.getJSON("/ReleaseView/GetAppsReport", { Business: Businessvalue, region: Regionvalue }, function (data) {


                //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                var columnSet = [];
                var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var rowHash = data[i];
                    for (var key in rowHash) {
                        if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
                            columnSet.push(key);
                            headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
                        }
                    }
                }
                $(selector).append(headerTr$);




                var columns = columnSet;

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
                        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
                            var cellValue = data[i][columns[colIndex]];
                            if (cellValue == null) cellValue = "";
                            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
                        }
                        $(selector).append(row$);
                    }










            })
        }
```

Comment: In general use plain JavaScript for intensive processing tasks. You should either split the data in chunks and display the data with pages or use setInterval() to always insert a small amount of rows. This way you have a responsive UI and you see results right at the beginning to work with ...

Comment: You append in every loop, this is quite the worst solution you can do. Instead its better to write it down in a var and append that or even better write it an array and join it. With native innerHTMl like its done here https://jsperf.com/jquery-append-vs-html-list-performance/24

Comment: you copy pasted the question.. including upvotes and downvotes

Comment: Voting to delete a pointless duplicate.